# WPA Passphrase Not Working for Raspberry Pi as Wireless Router

Tags: raspberry-pi, router, hostapd

I have set my Raspberry Pi 3 as a wireless router per instructions [here](https://www.instructables.com/id/Use-Raspberry-Pi-3-As-Router/), so that now it has the following contents in /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf.

```
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
ssid=rspi
hw_mode=g
channel=7
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=12341234
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

It now broadcasts the expected SSID ("rspi"), but none of my wireless devices can connect to it because of wrong password, even though I check closely that the password I type to connect is 12341234.

I tried in vain to change the channel number to 1, 6, and 8.

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect password can often mean that something else is wrong. I know when my raspberry pi says the password is wrong, and I know it's right, it's either still booting or it's failing to authenticate. Don't know how to fix it besides rebooting/ reimagining it to start the setup from scratch.